# Permeable Graphs (see inside)

Tags: graph-theory

You surely know the cheat to solve the gas/water/electricity (read: $K_{3,3}$) puzzle: Run a foreign pipe through a house.
So I define a permeable graph to be one where the nodes are drawn as fat blobs (sorry, "fat graph" was taken :-) and you may run an edge through it.
It should take you one second to realize all permeable graphs are planar. (Actually, I needed a minute but I got no sleep yesterday :-) In this form the definition is uninteresting and has to be restricted (since this fancy drawing mode is only relevant to crossings). Say, a 1-n-permeable graph is where you may run exactly one edge (not more) through any node, or a n-1-permeable graph is where you may only run edges through a node of your choice.
Since I'm always fast with conjectures, I have a hunch that a single fat node has the same effect as converting the topology to a body with a single hole and all rules about planarity of permeable graphs follow from that. (E.g. 1-1-permeable suffices to make $K_{3,3}$ and $S_5$ planar.) Is this actually true? (I bet someone had the notion before me.)